# Selecting an item from a list with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to select an item from a list with selenium / python and am having issues with getting the elements to load and be interactable. I think the problem is the website doesn't load the html for that section until the drop down is clicked but I'm not sure how to go about resolving that. This is what the html looks like if I click view source:

```
<label data-lang="4003">Impact</label>
<select id="impact">
    <option value="" selected data-lang="48">Select</option>
</select>
```

If I look at it with the chrome inspect tools I see this:

```
<label data-lang="4003">Impact</label>
<div class="select-wrapper cascading-dropdown-loading initialized">
  <span class="caret">▼</span>
  <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-e89d2a9c-3be1-67a1-6f4b-32c36b38f6eb" value="Select">
  <ul id="select-options-e89d2a9c-3be1-67a1-6f4b-32c36b38f6eb" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
    <li class="">
      <span>Select</span>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <span>High</span>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <span>Medium</span>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <span>Low</span>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <span>None</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <select id="impact" class="initialized" data-select-id="e89d2a9c-3be1-67a1-6f4b-32c36b38f6eb">                          
    <option value selected data-lang="48">Select</option>
    <option value="HIGH">High</option>
    <option value="MEDIUM">Medium</option>
    <option value="LOW">Low</option>
    <option value="NONE">None</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The data-select-id also seems to be randomly generated, as it changes each time I refresh the page.

So far, I've been able to get a list of the options available using the following code:

```
select = driver.find_element_by_id("impact")
options = [x for x in select.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
for element in options:
    print(element.get_attribute("value"))
```

Attempting to manipulate the list with something like element.click() doesn't seem to work and only gives me the error "Error: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"

I have also tried using Select with code like this with no success. I've used all three select by options, `select_by_value`, `select_by_visible_test` and `select_by_index` with no success.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('impact'))
select = select_by_value("HIGH")
```

I have also tried exploring `select.options` which returns a list of objects that look like:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="513ab2b2bfc1c3c738af19e69230a763", element="d00bf83d-3772-4357-b6da-1702a12ffda3")>
```

but I'm not sure how to manipulate these to do anything more with them. The session and element ids also change between runs.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you share the URL of the site from where you are trying to get this content? I think I can help you with this but in order to do that, I need to inspect that page.

Comment: Requires a login to get to the page sadly. Is there anything in particular you are looking for?